# Can I work with local database without LINQ to SQL in WP8?

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql, windows-phone-8

I trying to make simple WP8 application. In MSDN I found an [example for working with local database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202860%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). But  in this example using LINQ TO SQL. I dislike LINQ to SQL and my question:

Can I work with local database without LINQ to SQL in WP8?  For example, I want to use a code style like that:

```
IRepository{
   TestItem GetTestItem();
}

SQLCERepository:IRepository{
    public TestItem GetTestItem(){
        TestItem result=null;
       //making "select id, name from TEST_ITEM"
       //mapping "select" result into TextItem class
       return result;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't:

> **ExecuteCommand is not supported**: Windows Phone does not support executing “raw” Transact-SQL, Data Definition Language (DDL), or Data Modeling Language (DML) statements.

([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202872%28v=vs.105%29.aspx))

That is, you can't directly access the Transact-SQL database software built into Windows Phone 8. You can, however, add database SDKs to access other kinds of SQL databases, [for example SQLite](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/working-with-sqlite-in-windows-phone-8-a-sqlite-net-version-for-mobile/).